# Pip version error when installing package even though pip has been updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyenv

I'm gertting this error when I try to install `dateutil`:

```
Collecting dateutil

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dateutil (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dateutil
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

If I run `pip -V` I get this:

```
pip 19.0.1 from /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Have I configured something worng? How do I get dateutil insatalled?

Comment: there is a package named `python-dateutil` and another named `dateutils`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct package:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
For Python3:
`pip3 install python-dateutil`

For Python2:
`pip install python-dateutil`

Answer (score 0):

It's not error. It's just warning message. If you see in console it should be printed in yellow color. Error are normally displayed in red color.
And you are unable to install it because you have spelled it wrongly.
as **tebjorn** put in comment, its dateutils 
so use below command

```
pip install dateutils
```